# CalendarDatePicker, TodayDate is not highlighted in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

My Xaml:

```
<Grid >
    <Canvas Width="1000" Background="White">
        <CalendarDatePicker CalendarViewStyle="{StaticResource CalendarDatePickerCalendarViewStyle1}" 
                            CalendarViewDayItemChanging="CalendarDatePicker_CalendarViewDayItemChanging"
                            PlaceholderText="dd\mm\yyyy" Width="222" Height="32"
                            Canvas.Left="350" Canvas.Top="30"
                            DateChanged="CalendarDatePicker_DateChanged" 
                            IsTodayHighlighted="False"></CalendarDatePicker>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

My C# code :

```
    private void CalendarDatePicker_CalendarViewDayItemChanging(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.Date.Date.Equals(DateTimeOffset.Now.Date))
        {
            CalendarViewDayItem calendarViewDayItem = e.Item;
            calendarViewDayItem.Style = (Style)Resources["TodayhighlightCalendarViewDayItemStyle"];
        }
    }

    private void CalendarDatePicker_DateChanged(CalendarDatePicker sender, CalendarDatePickerDateChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        string selectedDate = args.NewDate != null ? args.NewDate.ToString() : "" ;
    }
```

My Complete Source code : [Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15ri8c4elc1RxCSSkQNmku1487m5t8jeR?usp=sharing)

What I have tried is?

I want to highlight the today Date with customStyle. So, I set CalendarDatePicker property, IsTodayHighlightProperty=false.
And then, I made a CustomStyle("TodayhighlightCalendarViewDayItemStyle") for highlighting the TodayDate.I done this using CalendarViewDayItemChanging event. Until this,works fine.
But the problem is, in the year view and decade view ,the today date is not highlighted because of setting IsToodayHighlightProperty as false. How to set the Today, year and month ForgroundColor as Red?

How Month view looks like?

[image]

How Year view looks like?

[image]

In the year view ,today date is not Highlighted(September 2021) as well as in decade view also.How to highlight it ?I need both background and forground highlight.

Comment: Do you mean the monthly grid has not highlight effect, right  ?

Comment: yes both monthly and yearly.

Comment: Why not use default IsTodayHighlighted propety ?

Comment: I need different style for TodayHighlighted .If I set IsTodayHighlighted=true,it provides default style.To stop default highlight,I set IstodayHighlighted property as false.I provide GDrive link for Complete code.Kindly look into it and suggest some solution.

Comment: Yep, I checked your code, after researching, we can't find any xaml code to set the default selecteditem  style. and it looks set in the code behind.

Comment: You could use vs live visual tree to check the monthly item type is `CalendarViewItem` , But it was not public.

Comment: Is there any other way ?I also working on this for last one week ,but I can't find a way!!

Comment: It's hard to say, but you could post feature request with in windows feed back hub or post it in Win UI github.